# Batch command to find and run file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, window, cmd, directory

Simple batch command line to find textfile.txt from C: drive, and run it.
Tried to find one but didn't see anywhere, so thats why Im asking it here.
So, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /s c:\textfile.txt') do "%%~fi"
```